# Textual reference software development. GUI alternatives?

Tags: database, sorting, reference, filtering

Below is a youtube video showing the functionality of a textual reference program. The program has embedded technical information in it and lets you navigate through the relevant information by selecting parameters. I happen to have this program and I found out that it uses a Microsoft Access Database to do the sorting and filtering of the information.

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iok87E1asoY

I'm trying to create a software that does the same thing without all the hassle of creating my own software and linking it to a MS Access database. To do this I'm hoping there is some software already out there that has a GUI to build these 'knowledge databases' and filters for them.

The basic mechanism I'm trying to achieve is to have a huge list of textual information in the background, and then have checkboxes and drop down menus (like in the video) to conditionally filter through the entire textual information and pull only the relevant bits and spit them out.

For example, let's use Vehicle Traffic rules.

- If traffic light is green, go through.
- If traffic light is red, don't go through.
- If traffic light is yellow, slow down.
- If traffic light is green, yellow, or red and there is a live ambulance nearby, slow down and pull over out of the way if possible.

So then you would have a drop down menu asking what color the traffic light is. And a checkbox asking if a live ambulance is nearby.

If you select "traffic light is Red" from the drop down menu, the program would display the "Don't go through the intersection" message or "Stop. Don't go." And the other obvious messages if you selected Green or Yellow.

If the checkbox is ticked indicating a live ambulance is nearby, it doesn't matter what color the traffic light is, you will get the "slow down and pull over if possible" message.

This becomes useful when you have a ton of information, and instead of having to read hundreds of pages for each time you need to find out what to do, you can filter through it quickly.

Comment: You're basically looking for either a faceted search mechanism, or a rules engine, or a combination of both. I'd start by searching for those terms, or related terms. The potential issue is that if you're operating in a specific domain, a generic approach may not be the most appropriate.